# Sum of the number of unique factors of numbers from 1 to 100?

Tags: prime-factorization

I want to compute

$\sum_{i\; =\; 1}^{i\; =\; 100}{d\left( i \right)}$

where d(i) is the number of factors of i. For example, for 1 it is 1, for 2 is is 2, for 3 it is 2, for 12 it is 6, and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by unique factors?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Why would 5 not appear?

Comment: By brute force, using the fact that if $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, the number of divisors is $(a_1+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$. There are good **estimates** of the sum up to $n$, but for exactness one more or less has to do it the hard way. We can save a bit by Inclusion/Exclusion methods, probably not worthwhile for $n=100$.

Comment: Why are you counting $1$ only once, but $2$ twice and $5$ not at all?

Comment: Guys, I agree s/he wasn't very clear, but OP means to compute $\sum_{i=1}^{100} d(i)$ where $d(i)$ is the number of factors of $i$.

Comment: It is unique with respect to the number. If a factor appears more than once for a number, you only count it once.

@user43208 Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $1$ is a divisor of every number in the set $[100]=\{1,\ldots,100\}$, so it contributes $100$ to the total count of divisors. $2$ is a divisor of the even numbers in $[100]$; there are $50$ of those, so $2$ contributes $50$ to the total count of divisors. Keep going: if $d$ is a positive integer, how many numbers in $[100]$ have $d$ as a divisor? Clearly you need only look at positive integers $d\le 100$, and you can deal with sum of them in batches rather than individually. For instance, how much does each $d$ in $\{51,52,\ldots,100\}$ contribute to the total?

Comment: How would you determine the batches, and how do you know that each number in the batch contributes the same?

Comment: @user2612743: Think about it: if $51\le d\le 100$, $d$ can have only one multiple in $[100]$, so there is exactly one $i$ in your summation whose $d(i)$ includes a multiple of $d$. Now what’s the range of values of $d$ for which $d$ has exactly $2$ multiples in $[100]$? Clearly the largest is $50$; what’s the smallest?

Comment: Ah.. got it! You can find the blocks by solving $# <= 100/x < #+1$ where # is the number of multiples you want. (Which is equivalent to $floor(100/x) = #$)

Comment: @user2612743: Or use the floor function, which amounts to the same thing: if $\left\lfloor\frac{100}d\right\rfloor=m$, you get $k$ multiples of $d$ (as I see you know have). `\lfloor` and `rfloor`

Answer (score 1):

Well, to me it's not a pleasant problem to do by hand, and I don't have any really slick ideas beyond what André Nicolas put down, but it might help to try to organize the calculation in terms of "Young tableaux" (which is essentially a fancy term for a finite list of positive integers in decreasing number).

The idea is to sort the numbers 1 through 100 into separate bins according to the list of nonzero prime exponents in the prime factorization. If $n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \ldots p_k^{e_k}$, then the number of factors or divisors $d(n)$ is $(e_1 + 1)(e_2 + 1) \ldots (e_k + 1)$, as André wrote. I'll always arrange the primes so that $e_1 \geq e_2 \geq \ldots$.

So: start by listing all the primes between 1 and 100: there are 25. This means there are 25 numbers where the prime exponent list is $e_1 = 1$. The number of divisors for each is $e_1 + 1 = 2$.

There are 30 numbers who prime exponent list is $1, 1$. These include numbers like $6 = 2 \cdot 3$, $10 = 2 \cdot 5$, $15 = 3 \cdot 5$, and so on. The number of divisors is $(e_1 + 1)(e_2 + 1) = 2 \cdot 4 = 4$.

There are 4 numbers who prime exponent list is $2$, because there are just four squares of primes from 1 to 100. Each has $2 + 1 = 3$ divisors.

And so on.

I get the following counts, but you should double-check. I've have put some questions marks for you to fill in as an exercise. The first entry is "empty" in the first column because the number 1 does not have any nonzero prime exponents.

> Exponent list | Number of numbers corresponding to that list | Number of divisors for each
>
> (empty) | 1 | 1
>
> 1 | 25 | 2
>
> 1, 1 | 30 | 4
>
> 2 | 4 | 3
>
> 1, 1, 1 | 4 | 8
>
> 2, 1 | 15 | 6
>
> 3 | 2 | ?
>
> 1, 1, 1, 1 | 0
>
> 2, 1, 1 | 3 | ?
>
> 2, 2 | 2 | ?
>
> 3, 1 | 5 | ?
>
> 4 | 2 | ?
>
> 3, 1, 1 | 1 | ?
>
> 2, 2, 1 | 0
>
> 3, 2 | 1 | ?
>
> 4, 1 | 2 | ?
>
> 5 | 1 | ?
>
> 5, 1 | 1 | ?
>
> 6 | 1 | ?

You will notice that the sum of numbers in the second column is 100, which gives me confidence that I counted correctly. The rest is up to you.